# Square root from double radical

Tags: radicals

I'm learning math, and found some interesting example.
$$
\sqrt {2-\sqrt 3} = \frac{1}{\sqrt {2+\sqrt 3}}
$$

Can you please explain me, why this happend. I guess that it depend on limits, but I still don't understand

Comment: multiply the LHS by $\frac{\sqrt{2+\sqrt 3}}{\sqrt{2+\sqrt 3}}$.

Comment: This uses $(a+b)(a-b)=a^2-b^2$ and is often used to remove square roots from denominators (e.g. in going from right to left in your expression)

Comment: What makes you think that this is in any way connected to limits?

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos Cuz, I found on wikipedia that radical from 3, can be written as $$
-1 + 2\sqrt{\frac{1}{2}+\sqrt{\frac{1}{2} + ...}}
$$ and I think that I can use limits to  prove this

Comment: @Surb and Henry Hah, it's was so easy, I don't think about it -_-. Thank you

Comment: Note that $\sqrt{2-\sqrt3}\times\sqrt{2+\sqrt3}=1$. And $ab=1$ imply $a=\frac1b$ and $b=\frac1a$.